# How to transform nested object property during (de)serialization using Symfony Serializer component?

Tags: php, symfony, serialization

I'm trying to change the representation of some properties while (de)serializing my data. I'm using the [Symfony Serializer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html) component (not in the framework context).

Here is the data I receive:

```json
{
    "object": {
        "id": 99,
        "price": "1000.0" // float inside a string
    }
}
```

```php
declare(strict_types=1);

class MyObject
{
    private int $id;
    private float $price;

    // Getters & setters
}
```

The problem is I can't find a way to deserialize `price` in a float:

```php
class Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->serializer = new Serializer([
            new ObjectNormalizer(
                classMetadataFactory:       new ClassMetadataFactory(new AnnotationLoader()),
                nameConverter:              new CamelCaseToSnakeCaseNameConverter(),
                propertyAccessor:           PropertyAccess::createPropertyAccessor(),
                propertyTypeExtractor:      new ReflectionExtractor(),
                classDiscriminatorResolver: null,
                objectClassResolver:        null,
                defaultContext:             [ObjectNormalizer::DISABLE_TYPE_ENFORCEMENT => true]
            ),
        ], [
            new JsonEncoder(),
        ]);
    }

    public function getMyObject()
    {
        // TypeError: MyObject::setPrice(): Argument #1 ($price) must be of type float, string given
        $myObject = $this->serializer->deserialize($json, MyObject::class, 'json');
    }
}
```

I tried to create a normalizer but [`AbstractObjectNormalizer`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/bb1e1e58aea5318e96d1c22cc8a91668ed7baaaa/src/Symfony/Component/Serializer/Normalizer/AbstractObjectNormalizer.php#L520) only ask for other normalizer when dealing with objects, not scalar types.

Anybody knows how to convert the price `string` in a `float` using the serializer? I could accept string in `MyObject::setPrice(string|float $price)` but I won't change the signatures.

Comment: If `setPrice` has the parameter hinted as `float`, then supplying a valid numerical string should automatically cast it into a float.

Comment: Thanks but what if I want to serialize the object, it should be a `string` but the serializer will encode a `float`

Comment: For some reason I completely neglected the parentheses in your title and only considered deserialization. It's been a while since I've dabbled with serializers, I'll have a look later.

Comment: Sorry, I came up short. My Symfony-fu has deteriorated lately and all the suggestions I find online focus on getters and setters. I'm not giving up fully, though. I'm intrigued now if this can be pulled off without touching the models.